The justify-between tailwind is working on the other files, but it's not working on the file I am currently working on

This is the output that tailwind is giving me instead of:

Here is the code block of the calendar style that I am currently working on. The code block in the <!--The section is not working --> is the thing that's not working. I tried using the developer console and I don't understand what's the thing I did wrong.
<!-- Calendar Section Start -->
<section class="pt-24">
  <div class="flex">
    <div
      class="calendar-container mx-10 my-5 rounded-md border border-black py-10"
    >
      <div class="appointment-counselor-container mx-5 flex justify-between">
        <div class="text-2xl font-semibold text-green-700">
          <h1>Appointments</h1>
        </div>
        <!-- Counselor toggle -->
        <div class="relative select-none">
          <!--The section is not working -->
          <div
            id="counselor-lists"
            class="bg-berde flex w-full cursor-pointer items-center justify-between rounded px-10 py-1 text-white"
          >
            <div class="my-auto">
              <h1 id="selected-counselor">Counselor 1</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="text-lg">
              <p>&#8744;</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div
            id="dropdown-options"
            class="absolute left-0 top-full mt-2 hidden w-full rounded border border-black bg-white"
          >
            <div
              class="cursor-pointer px-4 py-2 hover:bg-green-400"
              data-value="counselor1"
            >
              Counselor 1
            </div>
            <div
              class="cursor-pointer px-4 py-2 hover:bg-green-400"
              data-value="counselor2"
            >
              Counselor 2
            </div>
            <div
              class="cursor-pointer px-4 py-2 hover:bg-green-400"
              data-value="counselor3"
            >
              Counselor 3
            </div>
            <div
              class="cursor-pointer px-4 py-2 hover:bg-green-400"
              data-value="counselor4"
            >
              Counselor 4
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Counselor toggle end -->
      </div>

      <div class="pick-paragraph mx-5 my-2">
        <p class="text-base text-green-800">
          Pick a date and time for an appointment.
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="month-button-container mx-5 my-3 flex justify-between">
        <div class="my-auto text-green-800">
          <h1 id="month-year" class="text-2xl font-semibold"></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="month-button-wrapper flex text-2xl text-white">
          <div
            class="less-than-button my-auto cursor-pointer rounded px-5 py-2"
            id="prev"
          >
            <h1>&lt;</h1>
          </div>
          <div
            class="greater-than-button my-auto ml-2 cursor-pointer rounded px-5 py-2"
            id="next"
          >
            <h1>&gt;</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bg-berde grid grid-cols-7 text-white">
        <div class="mx-auto px-7 py-3 text-center text-lg font-semibold">
          Sun
        </div>
        <div class="mx-auto px-7 py-3 text-center text-lg font-semibold">
          Mon
        </div>
        <div class="mx-auto px-7 py-3 text-center text-lg font-semibold">
          Tue
        </div>
        <div class="mx-auto px-7 py-3 text-center text-lg font-semibold">
          Wed
        </div>
        <div class="mx-auto px-7 py-3 text-center text-lg font-semibold">
          Thu
        </div>
        <div class="mx-auto px-7 py-3 text-center text-lg font-semibold">
          Fri
        </div>
        <div class="mx-auto px-7 py-3 text-center text-lg font-semibold">
          Sat
        </div>
      </div>
      <div
        class="my-2 grid cursor-pointer grid-cols-7 text-center text-xl font-semibold"
        id="days"
      ></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- Calendar Section End -->

And here is the code block that doesn't work:
<div
  id="counselor-lists"
  class="bg-berde flex w-full cursor-pointer items-center justify-between rounded px-10 py-1 text-white"
>
  <div class="my-auto">
    <h1 id="selected-counselor">Counselor 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="text-lg">
    <p>&#8744;</p>
  </div>
</div>

This code works in other files, but not in this one. Why does justify-between not work in this file?

I have tried your code in tailwind play and it works normally. Create reproduceable example in codepen, jsfiddle, codesandbox or stackblitz.

The code block you pointed out actually works, and the issue isn’t with justify-between. The reason it didn't expand in width is that it's indirectly within a flex container. When inside a flex container, if you don't add flex-grow to the child elements, they will shrink to the content size. So the solution is quite simple: in Tailwind, you just need to add grow to the child element.


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="calendar-container mx-10 my-5 rounded-md border border-black bg-green-400 py-10">
  <div class="appointment-counselor-container mx-5 flex justify-between">
    <div class="text-2xl font-semibold text-green-700">
      <h1>Appointments</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- Counselor toggle -->
    <div class="relative select-none grow">
      <!-- This section now works because the parent container adds `grow` -->
      <div id="counselor-lists" class="bg-berde flex w-full cursor-pointer items-center justify-between rounded px-10 py-1 text-white">
        <div class="my-auto">
          <h1 id="selected-counselor">Counselor 1</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="text-lg">
          <p>&#8744;</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Counselor toggle end -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



Here's an example that better fits your design:


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="calendar-container mx-10 my-5 rounded-md border border-black bg-green-400 py-10">
  <div class="appointment-counselor-container mx-5 flex gap-4">
    <div class="text-2xl font-semibold text-green-700">
      <h1>Appointments</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- Counselor toggle -->
    <div class="relative grow select-none">
      <!-- This section now works because the parent container adds `grow` -->
      <div id="counselor-lists" class="bg-berde ml-auto flex max-w-64 cursor-pointer items-center justify-between rounded bg-green-700 px-4 py-1 text-white">
        <div class="my-auto">
          <h1 id="selected-counselor">Counselor 1</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="text-lg">
          <p>&#8744;</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Counselor toggle end -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



Demo on Tailwind Play.

It worked! I appreciate your time and effort to solve my problem :D
